# A shop sells three types of light bulbs. A customer get a random light bulb - what is the mean-lifetime and variance of the light bulb?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

**Exercise:**

A shop sells three types of light bulbs. The lifetime for the three light bulbs is exponential distributed with mean $1, 1.2$ and $1.4$, respectively. In the store $25$ % of the light bulbs are of the first type, $40$ % of the second type and $35$ % of the third type. A customer get a random light bulb - what is the mean-lifetime and variance of the light bulb ?

**Idea:**

Let $A,B,C$ denote the three types of light bulbs.

Then I cannot let be $ X$ a random variable with possible "values" $A,B,C$ ? I mean $A,B,C$ are not real numbers, but even thus $X$ is discrete in nature ?

$E(X)$ would then be $0.25 E(A) + 0.40 E(B) + 0.35 E(C) = 1.22$, but what about the variance $E(X^2)-(E(X))^2$ ? How do I square $X$ ?

Comment: It is more something like: let $X$ be the lifetime and let $A,B,C$ denote the *events* that the light bulb is of the first, the second and the third type respectively. That leads to $\mathbb{E}X=\mathbb{E}\left(X\mid A\right)P\left(A\right)+\mathbb{E}\left(X\mid B\right)P\left(B\right)+\mathbb{E}\left(X\mid C\right)P\left(C\right)=\mathbb{E}\left(X\mid A\right)0.25+\mathbb{E}\left(X\mid B\right)0.40+\mathbb{E}\left(X\mid C\right)0.35$

Comment: Why did you delete [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/768620/6179) after it got an answer? Are these just bad manners or what?

Answer (score 1):

By the [law of total expectation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation),
$$
\operatorname EX^2=\operatorname E(X^2\mid A)\Pr(A)+\operatorname E(X^2\mid B)\Pr(B)+\operatorname E(X^2\mid C)\Pr(C),
$$
where $A$, $B$ and $C$ are events that a randomly taken light bulb is of the type $1$, $2$ and $3$ respectively.

The second moment of the [exponential distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) is given by $\frac2{\lambda^2}$.

Comment: Thank you V.C.. So we let $X$ denote the light bulb chosen by random and then $A,B,C$ denote the three types of light bulbs and we know their distribution in the shop, and we use this distribution $(0.25, 0.40,0.35)$ as the probabilities for the light bulbs ? And finally we can easily calculate $E(X^2)$ given that we know it is a specific light bulb among $A,B,C$ ?.

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen I'm glad I could help! $X$ is the lifetime of a randomly chosen lightbulb. We know the probabilities of randomly chosing a lightbulb of type $A$, $B$ and $C$ ($0.25$, $0.4$ and $0.35$). Yes, we can easily calculate $\operatorname E(X^2\mid A)$ since we know the distribution of the lifetime of a lightbulb of type $A$.

Comment: Ahh so the sample space is $(A,B,C)$ and $Y$ is defined on this sample space ? And also $X$ is defined on this sample space as the function that computes the mean-lifetime of a lightbulb. But  what values does $Y$ takes on for a given point in $(A,B,C)$ ? Also should the sample space only be real numbers ? $A,B,C$ denote light bulbs here.

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen The sample space for this experiment would be $\Omega=\{(l,b):l\in[0,\infty),b\in\{A,B,C\}\}$, where $l$ is the lifetime and $b$ is the type of a lightbulb. Why are you interested in the sample space of this experiment? You can answer the question fully withouth defining the sample space.

Comment: I'm using the formula $E(g(X,Y)) = E(G(y))$ where $G(y) := E(g(X,y)\mid Y = y)$ and here I set $g(X,Y) = X$ to compute $E(X)$ and $g(X,Y) = X^2$ to compute $E(X^2)$. What exactly does $X,Y$ denote here ?

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen I don't understand why you are using this formula. $\operatorname E(X^2\mid A)$ is the second moment of the exponential distribution with the parameter $\lambda=1$ and the second moment of the exponential distribution is given by $2/\lambda^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Can you find $\mathbb{E}Y^{2}=\text{Var}Y+\left(\mathbb{E}Y\right)^{2}$
for $Y$ [exponentially distributed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution)? Then use:

$\mathbb{E}X^{2}=\mathbb{E}\left(X^{2}\mid A\right)P\left(A\right)+\mathbb{E}\left(X^{2}\mid B\right)P\left(B\right)+\mathbb{E}\left(X^{2}\mid C\right)P\left(C\right)$

And finally use:

$\text{Var}X=\mathbb{E}X^{2}-\left(\mathbb{E}X\right)^{2}$

Comment: So $X$ is the life bulb chosen at random on sample space $(A,B,C)$. Does $Y$ also denote the life bulb chosen at random, so $X$ and $Y$ are the same random variables ?

I'm using the formula $E(g(X,Y)) = E(G(y))$ where $G(y) := E(g(X,y)\mid Y = y)$ and here I set $g(X,Y) = X$ to compute $E(X)$ and $g(X,Y) = X^2$ to compute $E(X^2)$. 

Is it allowed for $X,Y$ to be equal ?

Comment: $Y$ mentioned in my answer plays no real part in your problem. I only invoked it in order to ask you the question: can you find the expectation of squares by exponentially distributed rv's?

Comment: Yes, I can. But in order to apply my formula. Could I set $X$ the mean-lifetime and $Y$ the type of light bulb ? Then these are defined on the same sample space ?

Comment: In order to model it properly you could say that $X=UA+VB+WC$ where
$U,V,W$ are exponentially distributed with parameters $1,1.2,1.4$
respectively and where $A,B,C$ are random variables independent of
$U,V,W$ taking values in $\left\{ 0,1\right\} $ is such a way that
$A+B+C=1$ and with $P\left[A=1\right]=0.25$, $P\left[B=1\right]=0.40$
and $P\left[C=1\right]=0.35$. Choosing for that you have $\mathbb{E}X=\mathbb{E}\left(X\mid A=1\right)P\left(A=1\right)+\mathbb{E}\left(X\mid B=1\right)P\left(B=1\right)+\mathbb{E}\left(X\mid C=1\right)P\left(C=1\right)$
and for square $X^{2}$ analogously.

Comment: That results in $\mathbb{E}X=\mathbb{E}\left(X\mid A=1\right)P\left(A=1\right)+\mathbb{E}\left(X\mid B=1\right)P\left(B=1\right)+\mathbb{E}\left(X\mid C=1\right)P\left(C=1\right)=\mathbb{E}U\times0.25+\mathbb{E}V\times0.40+\mathbb{E}W\times0.35$ For $X^2$ you can do the same thing.

Comment: Ahh nice, thank you. Could I also model it this way? $X$ is a random variable that denote the mean-lifetime of a randomly chosen light bulb from the sample space $(A,B,C)$. We don't know the exact distribution of $X$ (can we find it?), but thanks to the Law of Total Probability, we can compute the expectation of $X$ given the random variable $Y$ denoting a randomly chosen light bulb from the same sample space. However given that $Y=y$, we know the exact distribution of $X$ and therefore we can find the expectation ? (Have I understood it correctly?)

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen We are asked to stop this, and so I will. If things aren't clear yet, then you must pose another question. What you are saying does not make much sense to me. A sample space having random variables as elements? And secondly I see no essential difference between $X$ and $Y$ here. You just don't need such $Y$. The exact distribution of $X$ can be found with: $P[X\in S]=P[X\in S\mid A=1]P[A=1]+P[X\in S\mid B=1]P[B=1]+P[X\in S\mid C=1]P[C=1]=P[U\in S]P[A=1]+P[V\in S]P[B=1]+P[W\in S]P[C=1]$. That's it for today. Enjoy your study.