# Determine expected lifetime of a TV purchased from 1 of 3 factories, using LIE.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Problem Statement:

Consider a TV made in one of three factories, namely, A,B, and C. Note that the quality of work done at each factory is different. The pdf of time to failure, X, is given as $f_X^k(x)=\frac{1}{\lambda_k}e^{-\frac{x}{\lambda_k}}$ for $x\geq0$, zero otherwise, where $k=A,B,$ or $C$ and $\lambda_A=5,\lambda_B=6.5,$ and $\lambda_c=10.$ Here factory $A$ produces 3 times as many TVs as factory $B$ and factory $B$ produces twice as many TVs as factory $C$. The TVs are all sent to a central warehouse, mixed together, and then shipped to retail stores internationally. Determine the expected lifetime of a TV purchased at random from a store.

Attempted Solution:

Let $X$ denote the lifetime of a TV and $Y$ be the factory of manufacture. We must calculate $E[X].$

Let $N$ be the number of TVs produced in factory $C$. Then $2N$ is the number of TVs produced in factory $B$ and $6N$ for factory $A$. With this we have, $P(Y=A)=\frac{2}{3},P(Y=B)=\frac{2}{9},$ and $P(Y=C)=\frac{1}{9}$.

Using the LIE, we have $E[X]=E_Y[E_{X\mid Y}[X\mid Y]]$. Since the outcome space can be partitioned we can write
$$E[X]=E[X\mid Y=A]P(A)+E[X\mid Y=B]P(B)+E[X\mid Y=C]P(C)=\frac{2}{3}E[X\mid Y=A]+\frac{2}{9}E[X\mid Y=B]+\frac{1}{9}E[X\mid Y=C].$$

Now, for the first term we have,
$$E[X\mid Y=A]=\int_0^\infty xf_{X\mid Y}(x\mid Y=A)\,dx.$$

Using the wiki [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution#Mixed_case) for the Mixed case we have,
$$f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid Y=A)=\frac{P(Y=A\mid X=x)}{P(Y=A)}f_X^A(x).$$

Substituting this into the integral gives,
$$E[X\mid A]=\int_0^\infty x\frac{P(Y=A\mid X=x)}{P(Y=A)}f_X^A(x)\,dx.$$
This is as far as I can get. I'm unsure on how to compute $P(Y=A\mid X=x)$ for mixed random variables. I thought about grouping terms in the integrand to simplify the calculation, but couldn't come up with anything which helped.

I also found this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/768715/a-shop-sells-three-types-of-light-bulbs-a-customer-get-a-random-light-bulb-wh?rq=1), but it doesn't address my specific question. Moreover, I also looked at wiki page [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation), which provided an example to get me started.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It is $6N$ for Factory A. But you seem to have it right the rest of the way.

Comment: Oh, you're absolutely correct, let me fix that!

Comment: The (conditional) means for the various factories are given to you. The attempted integrations are not necessary.  For example the conditional mean for A is $5$.

Comment: So then what kind of approach should I take here? Do I calculate $E[X\mid A]$ using the pdf?

Comment: $(5)(1/2)+\cdots$

Comment: So $E[X\mid A]=\lambda_A$? I don't quite see that. What am I missing?

Comment: The exponential with density $(1/a)e^{-x/a}$ has mean $a$.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for your help. I'll think about it some more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the notation of the post, the probability $\Pr(A)$ that the TV comes from Factory A is $1/2$, and $\Pr(B)=1/3$, and $\Pr(C)=1/6$. We have, as in the post,
$$E(X)=E(X\mid A)\Pr(A)+E(X\mid B)\Pr(B)+E(X\mid C)\Pr(C).$$
A random variable that has density function $\frac{1}{d}e^{-x/d}$ for $x\gt 0$, and $0$ elsewhere, has mean $d$. This can be viewed as a standard fact about the exponential distribution. Or else we can show it by finding $\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{d}e^{-x/d}\,dx$ using integration by parts.

Thus $E(X\mid A)=5$. We also have been given the other two conditional expetations, so we have all the information required to finish.

Comment: I understand. It's blatantly given. Thank you for clearing it up for me.

Comment: You are welcome.